# How to fix alertView orientation on specific controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to fix orientation of a specific controllers.

I tried more times but I'm unable to fixed. I fixed the controller orientation in appdelegate method (supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor)  but cause of alert message orientation doesn't work proper and then that work normally. I mean it's work all type orientation.

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if !UIDevice.isIphone() {
        let controller = (application.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.visibleViewController
        if controller is LiveStreamViewController || controller is VideoStreamingViewController {
            return .portrait
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    } else {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what the goal is and what's happening instead.

Answer (score 0):

Orientation of a "specific controller" is not determined by implementing `application(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor:)`. It is determined from within the specific controller by implementing `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. And even then, this value is not consulted unless your view controller is topmost.

Answer (score 0):

Alert view surly rotted according to `Orientation` but if does not work then try to use below code

```
 func didPresent(_ alertView: UIAlertView) {
        // UIAlertView in landscape mode for specific controller?
        UIView.beginAnimations("", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.1)
        alertView.transform = alertView.transform.rotated(by: 3.14159 / 2)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }
```